# Why is $_SESSION array empty after filling it with value in js-script?

Tags: javascript, php, session, session-variables, session-storage

I'm trying to implement cart on my website. It works this way: user on catalog page is able to add product to the cart by clicking "Add to cart" button, data about product id and amount of it is writed to Session storage via JS. I'm struggling to output data from $_SESSION array on cart.php page. When I var_dump() it, PHP says that $_SESSION array is empty. **Why so? How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

PHP Session and Browser's session are two different things and you can't exchange the data between them directly.

1. You can save a cart in a local storage and display it in a form, then submit and save in a DB.
2. You can save a cart using PHP to PHP's session.
3. You can use AJAX to communicate with PHP to save/retrieve data from PHP's session.

Comment: I can use AJAX from JS to communicate with PHP Session, right?

Comment: I think I'll do as you suggested in the 1st point

Comment: That's probably gonna be the easiest solution

Comment: I've encountered with another problem. I'm trying to copy sessionStorage to variable named session via Object.assign(session, sessionStorage), but when I'm trying to alert() length of variable session it says "undefined". How can I copy sessionStorage to some variable?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add $_SESSION value or access it with js.
I think ajax can help you. Use Ajax.